# Android "open with" implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to open downloaded files in an Android app with Kotlin. For the moment I can open with the recommended app on the system by setting the type of the file with the below code

```
class Somelistener(private val workManager: WorkManager, private val adapter: someAdapter, private val lifecycle: LifecycleOwner) : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


private fun openWithOther(path: String?, context: Context?) {
    if (path == null || context == null) {
        return
    }
    val uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(File(path))
    val mime: String? = getMimeType(path)

    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(context, intent, null)
}
```

However, we need to not open directly the file but ask the user with a "open with" prompt where the user can tryout which app he wants to open it with.

Can this be done ? With what kind of intent ?

Secondary questions, not necessary for answer, at the startActivity with intent, the bundle should be null as i have it ? Also I cant seem to find some startActivity for result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What u are looking for is `App chooser`. U can create it via `Intent.createChooser(target, title)`. In your scenario it would be:

```kotlin
with(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
    setDataAndType(uri, mime)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(this, null)
    activity?.startActivity(chooserIntent)
}
```

See [App Chooser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#AppChooser)

Comment: This doesnt seem to have any difference to the code snippet i posted. Both result to prompt to open with recommended apps. 
I got from another developer that what i am trying to do cannot be done. To have a generic open with any application, not only recommended

Comment: u wrote "user can tryout which app he wants to open it with" and this is what `chooser` is meant for. If u want to display any app in the chooser, set the mime type to "*/*" -> `setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")`

Comment: The `Intent.createChooser` will create a picker with all the apps that support that type. You cannot open a file with an application that does not support it in its manifest.